# "Illegal view pattern: fromPathPiece -> Just dyn_abDD" when using parameters on routes

Tags: haskell, yesod

I'm using yesod version 1.4.0 within a cabal sandbox.

I have the following routes file:

```
/static StaticR Static getStatic
/auth   AuthR   Auth   getAuth

/favicon.ico FaviconR GET
/robots.txt RobotsR GET

/ HomeR GET POST
/config/#String MakeConfigR GET POST
```

and a matching (properly imported and everything) handler file for the implementation.

However, whenever yesod (or when I manually) try to compile, I get the following error

```
Foundation.hs:48:1:
    Illegal view pattern:  fromPathPiece -> Just dyn_abDD
    Use -XViewPatterns to enable view patterns
```

I haven't modified Foundation.hs in any way.

When I only have a route that takes no parameters, such as

```
/noparamshere NoParamsR GET
```

or something similar in my routes file, everything works fine. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you have created your project with an old version of yesod. As of yesod-1.4.0, you need to enable `ViewPatterns` extension as the error message indicates. Add `ViewPatterns` to `default-extensions` in your cabal file.

Comment: For more information on Yesod 1.4 upgrades, please see: http://www.yesodweb.com/blog/2014/09/announcing-yesod-1-4

Comment: for adding ViewPatterns to stack see https://meincodekraft.blogspot.com/2017/11/yesod-tutorial-for-beginners-haskell.html